# jdbc not in classpath error

Tags: java, jdbc, jar, classpath, weka

so I have a project that requires Weka machine learning library (weka.jar) and the mysql jdbc mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar

I have them both as part of my build path in the project....I also added them both to my CLASSPATH environment variable...so the project runs perfectly when I use Eclipse's run button...

but then after exporting the project as a standalone jar and run the java -jar theproject.jar command, 
it returns a whole bunch of errors:

```
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): RmiJdbc.RJDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH
?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): jdbc.idbDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): com.mckoi.JDBCDriver - Error, not in CLASS
PATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver - Error, not in CLAS
SPATH?
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:idb=experiments.prp
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected, please connect first!
```

even though it ran perfectly on eclipse and despite the fact that both weka.jar and mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar are in the CLASSPATH environment variable...

what did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you export the jar as runnable JAR from Eclipse?

Comment: As duffymo mentioned below, check your MANIFEST.MF file and see how your Class-path looks like.

Comment: also I packaged all the jdbc files into the jar so that they're also located within the jar....how would I specify the classpath then, if the jdbc files is inside the same jar as well....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have a CLASSPATH environment variable.

A standalone JAR needs a MANIFEST that spells out the CLASSPATH.  That's what the JDK is looking at, not your CLASSPATH environment variable.

Look at some tutorials showing how to do it.  You'll have it running outside Eclipse in no time.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/jar.html

Comment: is there a way to have eclipse do all this automatically so that I don't have to modify the manifest everytime I build it.....

Comment: You write it once.  There might be a way to tell Eclipse to add all your 3rd party JARs to a generated MANIFEST.MF.  I use InteliJ, so I'm not sure.